SRv6 not working in docker containers although it works on the host os
I am trying to experiment with segment routing using three Docker containers. I want to route a packer from container router1 to container router3 using srv6.
When I attempt to encapsulate an SRv6 header in my packet with the following command:
ip -6 route add fc00::8 encap seg6 mode encap segs fcf0:12::101 dev eth0
I receive the following error in the logs:
router1 | Error: lwt encapsulation type not supported.
However, this command executes successfully on my host OS, which is Ubuntu.
I am running the containers in privileged mode and granting them full access to the host kernel. Here is the configuration for one of the containers (router1):
router1:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: router1
    privileged: true
    network_mode: "host"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - ./entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh && /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"


Does anyone have any insight into why this is not working within the containers and what I can do to make it run?

That Compose fragment doesn't seem to be using Docker in any meaningful way, other than running a shell interpreter in a container rather than from the host and then trying to escape the container environment to change the host's network setup.  sudo ./entrypoint.sh without Docker will probably be much simpler.
